# C# Get form names of project A from Project B

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have two Projects in one solution, `project A` and `project B` (`using VS2010 Ultimate and C# windows application`).
`Project B` acts as a user management application for `project A`.
In `project B` i have a form that contains a `chekcedlistbox` control that will list all `project A` forms names and texts (this form will let system administrator to grant users the forms that are allowed to view/edit based on their security groups)
this is my code:

```
   private void GetFormNames()
    {
        foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
            {
                if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
                {
                    var emptyCtor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                    if (emptyCtor != null)
                    {
                        var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                        string FormText = f.Text;
                        string FormName = f.Name;
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add("" + FormText + "//" + FormName + "");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

the result i am getting is the form names of my current project (B) and Empty lines(//) and `Select Window//MdiWindowDialog`, `PrintPreview`.

Comment: And your question is? You expect something different? Why do you think so?

Comment: have you add an assembly reference to project A in project B?

Comment: Are you check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've referenced `ProjectA` correctly and all the forms you're interested in actually have a `public` parameterless constructor. The problem is likely caused by `ProjectA` not being loaded yet, you can fix this in multiple ways.  Probably the most direct is to use the [`static Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) (as long as the files are in the same directory, if not it gets more complicated).

```
try
{
    Assembly projectA = Assembly.Load("ProjectA"); // replace with actual ProjectA name 
    // despite all Microsoft's dire warnings about loading from a simple name,
    // you should be fine here as long as you don't have multiple versions of ProjectA
    // floating around

    foreach (Type t in projectA.GetTypes())
    {
        if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
        {
            var emptyCtor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            if (emptyCtor != null)
            {
                var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                // t.FullName will help distinguish the unwanted entries and
                // possibly later ignore them
                string formItem = t.FullName + " // " + f.Text + " // " + f.Name;
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(formItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception err)
{
    // log exception
}
```

Another (probably cleaner solution) would be to have all the forms you're interested in inherit from a single base form. You could then load the assembly from that known `Type` and check that each enumerated `Type` inherits from it before adding it to your list. This is a more extensive change, however, and touches `ProjectA`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); 
foreach (Assembly a in assemblies) 
{ 
    Type[] types = a.GetTypes(); 
    foreach (Type t in types) 
    { 
        if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form)) 
        { 
                  //Do Your works
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting here. Is it that storing the return values `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and `a.GetTypes()` in declared variables will make a difference? It defintiely won't. Are you saying the OP shouldn't change what's in the `if` statement? If so, you should be more clear and give a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
 private void GetFormNames()
    {


        Type[] AllTypesInProjects = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
            for (int i = 0; i < AllTypesInProjects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (AllTypesInProjects[i].BaseType == typeof(Form))
                {            /* Convert Type to Object */
                    Form f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(AllTypesInProjects[i]);
                    string FormText = f.Text; 
                    listBox1.Items.Add(FormText);
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: This is will return a subset of the forms the OP is already getting, it won't add anything.