# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting all "Form Name" from project A into project B as per given in

[C# Get form names of project A from Project B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118946/c-sharp-get-form-names-of-project-a-from-project-b)

and I am using **@jerry**'s answer.

when my code reached `var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });` line I am getting Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation Error.

below is full code

```
try
{
    Assembly projectA = Assembly.Load("ProjectA"); // replace with actual ProjectA name 
    // despite all Microsoft's dire warnings about loading from a simple name,
    // you should be fine here as long as you don't have multiple versions of ProjectA
    // floating around

    foreach (Type t in projectA.GetTypes())
    {
        if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
        {
            var emptyCtor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            if (emptyCtor != null)
            {
                var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                // t.FullName will help distinguish the unwanted entries and
                // possibly later ignore them
                string formItem = t.FullName + " // " + f.Text + " // " + f.Name;
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(formItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception err)
{
    // log exception
}
```

I was searched Error reason but failed. please suggest me we I am worng

**EDIT :**

below are Error details

**Image 1**
[image: Error1]

**Image 2**

[image: Err2]

Comment: Is there `InnerException` in error you get?

Comment: There's StackTrace in InnerException - you could have better understanding of what's wrong by examining it

Comment: @J0HN InnerException stack trace indicates that exception is thrown by `FrmMachineryType` constructor. It seems you also have debug info (`.pdb` files ) for this assembly and stack trace should contain line number that throws the exception. If you have access to source code you can check what causes the error. Probably form constructor tries to access some static object that was not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(null);
```

BTW, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void childclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtTrans = new DataTable();
    dtTrans = Db.bindData("SELECT frm_Code FROM tbl_MST_SubMnu WHERE frm_Name='" + sender.ToString() + "'");

    Assembly frmAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath);
    foreach (Type type in frmAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.BaseType == typeof(Form))
        {
            if (type.Name == dtTrans.Rows[0][0].ToString())
            {
                Form frmshow = (Form)frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString());

                frmshow.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```