# How to get all the forms inside my app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

I need to get  all the forms inside my c# application and add the .Text parameter for each one to a combobox control and i need to do all in one method (void)

myCode:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly[] assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach(System.Reflection.Assembly asem in assembly)
{
    foreach(Type t in asem.GetTypes())
    {   
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(t.Name);
        //here i need to get the .Text param
        //where Name is the Form name
    }
}
```

Comment: Which technology is this? WebForms? WinForms? WPF? ...?

Comment: Winforms technology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Get form names of project A from Project B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118946/c-sharp-get-form-names-of-project-a-from-project-b)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Application.OpenForms` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) to get a list of all currently open forms.

You *cannot* iterate all the types since you don't get the running instances but only the types. If you don't have an instance of a class, the class does not exist in memory.

(Just because a class is instantiated does not mean that it has a visual appearance, even if the class derives from `Form`).

Comment: @the2xbeaast How would that be ever possible? If you don't have an instance, they do not exist in memory.

Comment: then how to call each one without write each one ? and doing it in a method.